# C# - WinForm ComboBox Clearing On Button Click

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

I have a strange problem that I have been trying to fix for a week with no luck.

I have a combo box which is populated during form load, that clears itself when I click a button even though there is no code to do this.

The is populated with the results of a DB query using the code below:

```
private void FrmChart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listOfFunds = DatabaseLogic.GetListOfFunds();
    cboFundToDisplay.DisplayMember = "FundName";
    cboFundToDisplay.ValueMember = "FundName";
    cboFundToDisplay.DataSource = listOfFunds;
}
```

GetListOfFunds Code

```
public static DataTable GetListOfFunds()
{
    if (db == null)
    {
        db = new SqliteDatabase();
    }

    return db.ExecuteQuery(@"SELECT DISTINCT FundName FROM [DATA]");
}
```

This code works correctly and on loading the form, the combo box is populated.

There is also a button which when clicked takes the currently selected value from the combo box and gets the data for that "fund".  Once it has the data, it sets up a chart and displays the data.

This is also working as expected and the chart is displayed when the button is clicked.  This is done using the code below:

```
private void btnGetChartData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fundName = cboFundToDisplay.Text;

    DataTable dt = DatabaseLogic.GetDataForFund(fundName);

    if (crtMain.Series.Count > 0)
    {
        crtMain.Series.Clear();
    }

    crtMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = ChartLogic.GetMinimumValueWithBuffer("FundUnitPrice", dt, 1);
    crtMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = ChartLogic.GetMaximumValueWithBuffer("FundUnitPrice", dt, 1);

    crtMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = ChartLogic.GetMinimumValue("WeekNumber", dt);
    crtMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = ChartLogic.GetMaximumValue("WeekNumber", dt);

    crtMain.Series.Add(fundName);
    crtMain.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    crtMain.Series[fundName].XValueMember = "WeekNumber";
    crtMain.Series[fundName].YValueMembers = "FundUnitPrice";
    crtMain.DataSource = dt;
}
```

The issue I face is that when I click the button to update the chart, the combo box values all clear which is unexpected.

This clearance of the combo box happens somewhere within the method below:

```
DataTable dt = DatabaseLogic.GetDataForFund(fundName);
```

The strange thing is that if I move the code which is in this method (listed below) into the body of btnGetChartData_Click then it works and the combo box is not cleared.

```
public static DataTable GetDataForFund(string fundName)
{
    if (db == null)
    {
        db = new SqliteDatabase();
    }

    List<string> parameters = new List<string>();

    parameters.Add(fundName);

    return db.ExecuteQuery(@"SELECT ID, FundName, FundUnitPrice, WeekNumber FROM [DATA] WHERE [FUNDNAME] = @param1", parameters);
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for GetListOfFunds() also?

Comment: My guess is that the 'db' variable is being used by both functions and trying to reuse the same db variable is clearing the combobox.  when you copy the code you're making a new/different db variable to use.

Comment: Set up a watch for cboFundToDisplay.Items and see what step is actually clearing the items out.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have edited the post to add the GetListOfFunds code.  All of the DB code checks if the db object exists (not null) and creates an instance if not.  After the initialisation the connection is only closed so DB object should always exist.  I setup a watch on cboFundToDisplay, but the watch will go out of scope while in the other class and then when it comes back from the method to the form, its count is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the **db** variable that is being used by the data source. There must be some issue in code not shown that is causing it to reset the data source and thus clear the combobox.

Comment: The issue here was that the db variable was being reused and therefore when it tried to re-bind the data table to the combo box, it no longer had access to the information it needed because the db object was now being used to query a different set of data.  All fixed now.  Thanks for your help @David.